# Do environment variables distinguish system environment variables from application environment variables?

Tags: operating-system

Do environment variables distinguish system environment variables from application environment variables?
Or is it just a system environment variable?

---

**Edit-01**

my scenario is in Linux.
btw, does it have anything to do with the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way for a POSIX host to create a child process.
One of them is
[execle](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execle).

Note the `envp` argument.

An interactive shell, such as
[bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash),
can `export` a variable, or not.
Non-exported variables are uninteresting, they are not environment vars,
as they will not appear within `envp`.

You were wondering if there is a sys vs app distinction for env vars.
There is no such distinction.
Either a key=value entry appears in `envp`, or it does not.
If it does, then it is an env var. If it does not, it is some local setting
of interest only to the environment where it was assigned a value.
Fork a `/usr/bin/env` child if you want to see current env vars.

---

Another way is `execvpe`.

And yes, I know, the typical pattern is fork() and *then* exec.
Though BSD and others have experimented with variations on
that theme, to avoid expensive fork work which exec immediately
discards.